# Restrict users access on specific git branch repo and history repo, while keeping merge facilities

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, branch, restriction

- Here is my context:

  1. I have a software with 20 vesion, each version represents( is the same) a branch in my git repo.
  2. I Have two teams, one local and one remote.
- Here is my restrictions:

  1. Local team have full access to the repo.
  2. Remote team have access restrictively to 15th version(15th branch)
  3. Remoe team cant have access to history before 15th branch
  4. Remote team can´t have access to Local tema work
  5. remote team have acesso only to theier work
- Here is a premise:

  1. Would be awesome if the local team could be able to merge from remote team code, with minimum conflicts pain.
- What i have tryed?

  1. 1th
     I created a fork from the repo, and i garanted the master have only till 15th version. Some masrter and 15th branch are the some code version.
     The problem in this solution: the remote team still have access to all repo and history and code.
  2. 2th
     Create a new repo begining from 15th branch.
     The problem in this case, would be about when local team do the merge from remote to local codes team.

Till now, i would stay with the 2th option, even if i have merge issues.

So, anyone have a better solution or  more elegant?

Really hope made my self explained.

=====================================

I executed this commands:

> git clone --mirror --depth 1 --branch release/v15  https://carlotto_totem@bitbucket.org/old_repo.git
>
> cd old_repo
>
> git push --mirror https://carlotto_totem@bitbucket.org/new_repo.git

Than i got this message:

```
C:\old_repo>git push --mirror https://carlotto_totem@bitbucket.org/new_repo.git
Password for 'https://carlotto_totem@bitbucket.org':
Counting objects: 131, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (95/95), done.
Writing objects: 100% (131/131), 9.72 MiB | 238.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 131 (delta 28), reused 131 (delta 28)
To https://carlotto_totem@bitbucket.org/new_repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] release/v15 -> release/v15 (shallow update not allowed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://carlotto_totem@bitbucket.org/new_repo.git'
```

What should i do about?

> shallow update not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Do a shallow clone so you have only back till the 15th version.  Then push it to a new bare repository.  Allow the remote team only to access that new repository.  The local team should be able to pull from that as a second remote, and merge from remote to local.